# Is there a better way to insert records?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a class project building a library management system with mysql & php.

I have 3 items in library: books, audios, and videos. Each have different attributes and one item id.

**TABLES:**

```
 ITEM(item_id A.INCREMENT, TYPE)
 BOOK(b_id,name,author etc.)
 VIDEO(v_id, ETC.)
 AUDIO(a_id, ETC.)
```

However, I have to use 3 sql statements to add items to both specific table and item table.  Is there a better way to this? I don't need `ITEM` class actually, I use it just to be more general. Is it bad without it?

This is what is use.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO ITEM  values(NULL,'BOOK') ";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $sql="SELECT ID as id FROM ITEM  WHERE ID=last_insert_id()";
        $query=$this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
        $name =  $book_name;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKS values ('".$query['id']."','".$name."','".$author."','".$title."','".$year."','".$price."','AVAIBLE',NOW(),'0')";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: While this does not particularly fix your current issue, I would perhaps reorder my tables so that books, audio, and video were all in one table, with a column to differentiate what type of information is being displayed. (Much like Wordpress does with custom post types)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO ITEM (`type`) values ('BOOK');

INSERT INTO BOOKS (b_id, name, author) 
select last_insert_id(), '$name', '$author';
```

BTW if you use *Prepared Statements* your queries will be way more readable and protected against SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you, i dont know about prepared statements but i will search now.

Comment: In the second insert statement you dont specify its last inserted of ITEM table. How the method will take the id?

Comment: `last_insert_id()` returns the ID of the last insert. So that query does take the correct id. Your second query is useless :) That is like writing `select id from t where id = 123`. Well the result would be `123`.